# Non-conductive materials can't be grounded

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Is the titular question true? That means, after charges being gathered on comb, even if I connect a wire with the comb and ground it, the comb would not neutralize? Am I right?

Comment: It's physics......have you tried to test this?

Comment: Probably would neutralize over time since the plastic in the comb isn't a perfect insulator.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove charges from a plastic comb by attaching a wire to it, but you can ground a non-conductive material by immersing it into a conductive medium, whether gaseous (humid air), liquid (tap water), or solid (metal plating). All three methods are very effective specifically for a comb.

Answer (score 0):

The key property of an electrical isolator (= non-conductive material) is that  electrical charges are unable to flow through it. Hence, if charges are added onto the surface of the isolator they have to stay there, even if an other point of the isolator is grounded.

For example, air is an electrical isolator (at low voltages). That's why our current sockets in the house don't have to be shielded: Although the two pins of the socket provide a voltage different of some hundred volts (actual voltage depends on your country) no current flows if they are not connected.